# Can't build kudan iOS unity3d project

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, kudan

Get the following linking error trying to build against unity3d version 5.3.5f1

```
 Ld /Users/georgecook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bfwjzdbspnhgyjblhswtougxoafx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ar.app/ar normal arm64
    cd "/Users/georgecook/Documents/tantaWowa/projects/dontRobMyPlanet/git/New Unity Project/build/app"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -L/Users/georgecook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bfwjzdbspnhgyjblhswtougxoafx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/georgecook/Documents/tantaWowa/projects/dontRobMyPlanet/git/New\ Unity\ Project/build/app -L/Users/georgecook/Documents/tantaWowa/projects/dontRobMyPlanet/git/New\ Unity\ Project/build/app/Libraries -L/Users/georgecook/Documents/tantaWowa/projects/dontRobMyPlanet/git/New\ Unity\ Project/build/app/Libraries/KudanAR/Plugins/iOS -F/Users/georgecook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bfwjzdbspnhgyjblhswtougxoafx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/georgecook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bfwjzdbspnhgyjblhswtougxoafx/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ar.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/georgecook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bfwjzdbspnhgyjblhswtougxoafx/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/ar-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -liPhone-lib -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -weak_framework iAd -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lKudanPlugin -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/georgecook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bfwjzdbspnhgyjblhswtougxoafx/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ar_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/georgecook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-bfwjzdbspnhgyjblhswtougxoafx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ar.app/ar

ld: warning: object file (/Users/georgecook/Documents/tantaWowa/projects/dontRobMyPlanet/git/New Unity Project/build/app/Libraries/KudanAR/Plugins/iOS/libKudanPlugin.a(KARPlugin.o)) was built for newer iOS version (8.0) than being linked (7.0)
ld: '/Users/georgecook/Documents/tantaWowa/projects/dontRobMyPlanet/git/New Unity Project/build/app/Libraries/KudanAR/Plugins/iOS/libKudanPlugin.a(KARPlugin.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your error log, it's saying that Bitcode is not enabled for the framework.

You will need to disable Bitcode on your Xcode project in order for it to build.

Make sure to disable Bitcode on your project and your Targets. (https://wiki.kudan.eu/Building_the_app_-_iOS)